# Longest common sub-list

Tags: haskell

I need a function `f :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]` returning the longest sub-list of each of the list of lists supplied. E.g., `f [[1,2,3], [0,1,3], [1,3,4]] =
[1,3]`. [1,3] is defined to be a sub-List of `[1,2,3]`, therefore the elements of the sublist don't have to be in neighbouring positions of the super-list.

What I have thought so far is making a function let's call it: `findCombinations :: [a] -> [[a]]` that takes a list and returns all possible combinations of elements of that list. For example, `[1,2,3] -> [[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`, and then using that function for every sublist of the superlist in order to find all possible combinations for each sublist and then find the combinations that appears the most, however I am stuck with the implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: You may simply [`foldl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1) by [`Data.List.intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect) if i got you right. Such as `foldl1 intersect [[1,2,3], [0,1,3], [1,3,4]]` would result `[1,3]`.

Comment: @Redu thanks for your tip can you give any example?

Comment: "the longest sub-list of each of the list of lists", to me sounds like an intersection of multiple lists and your example supports that. Haskell is ready for this job out of the box. As mentioned in my above comment `foldl1` and `intersect` which lives in `Data.List` are sufficient. `foldl1 Data.List.intersect [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,4,4,5,6,7]]` would return `[3,4,5]`.

Comment: @Redu exactly that's my idea as well but I am not allowed to use Data.List or import any 3rd party library

Comment: Why only an `Eq` constraint? That's rather wimpy, and most *efficient* implementations of this function will want more. `Ord` would open up a lot more options.

Answer (score 1):

For your `findCombinations` function, you can adopt the following approach.

- there is only one sublist of `[]`, namely `[]` itself
- the sublists of `x:xs`, instead, have two forms:

  - the sublists of `xs`
  - the sublists of `xs`, where `x` has been added in front of each of them

You can start coding this by first defining a function `addToAll :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]` such that, for instance, `addToAll 2 [[1,5],[],[8,5,6]] = [[2,1,5],[2],[2,8,5,6]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you need can simply be done by using [foldl1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1) applied by [Data.List.intersect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect). Such as;

```
Prelude> foldl1 Data.List.intersect [[1,2,3], [0,1,3], [1,3,4]]
Prelude> [1,3]
```

`Data.List` is a very common library and many of it's inhabitants are default in Prelude such as `foldl1`. So it shouldn't be a big deal to import `intersect` from it. However `intersect` by itself is a very simple code and you may simply implement it yourself or [steal it from the definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#intersect). Let's do it;

```
Prelude> let isect xs ys = filter (\e -> any (== e) xs) ys
Prelude> foldl1 isect [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,4,4,5,6,7]]
[3,4,5]
```

So here you go. Your library agnostic function is.

```
f :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
f = foldl1 isect
```

Comment: 1) The question is not very clear, but I believe the OP wants the sublists, not the subsets; `intersection` ignores the order in the list elements, when it might matter (the longest sublists of "ab" and "ba" are "a" and "b", not "ab" nor "ba")  2) `(\e -> any (== e) xs)` can also be written ``(`elem` xs)``

Comment: @chi Well i don't think it's a problem since a slightest change in the sub lists will prevent the problem you mention. On the other hand checking if all sublists having exactly same elements in advance is a trivial job. So i guess no need for combinatronics here. The main problem here is with the built in `intersect` function since when you do like `foldl1 intersect [1,2,2,3] [1,2,4]` the result is `[1,2,2]`. Which brings me to the necessity of chaining a `nub` stage such as `nub . foldl1 intersect $ [[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9], [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6,7]]`